# VS Code Remote Development giving back error

Tags: linux, azure, virtual-machines, ssh-tunnel, remote

I'm trying to connect my Vs code using SSH extension to my Debian VM on azure.
I tried running the SSH connection on terminal and it's working fine
`ssh -i Desktop/Emdad/testing/magento-testing-key.pem azureuser@20.198.108.124`

But when I tried doing it on VS code, I get this error:
`

> C:\Users\Dell PC\Desktop\testing\magento-testing-key.pem: terminating, 39 bad configuration options                                                            [22:07:26.089] > The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
> [22:07:27.366] "install" terminal command done
> [22:07:27.368] Install terminal quit with output: g, 39 bad configuration options
> [22:07:27.368] Received install output: g, 39 bad configuration options
> [22:07:27.371] Failed to parse remote port from server output
> [22:07:27.374] Resolver error: Error:at m.Create (c:\Users\Dell PC.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.100.0\out\extension.js:1:584145)
> at t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\Dell PC.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.100.0\out\extension.js:1:582705)
> at t.tryInstall (c:\Users\Dell PC.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.100.0\out\extension.js:1:681555)
> at async c:\Users\Dell PC.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.100.0\out\extension.js:1:643798
> at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\Dell PC.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.100.0\out\extension.js:1:647116)
> at async t.resolve (c:\Users\Dell PC.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.100.0\out\extension.js:1:644848)
> at async c:\Users\Dell PC.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.100.0\out\extension.js:1:720590
> [22:07:27.393] ------`

I tried modifying the ssh_config file on my remote and add :
`#   PermitRootLogin yes`
on the 55 line, but didn't work, and I know the source of this issue is from the remote VM since I tried this process on couple machines. but same error.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar error and managed to get it working again by installing a previous version of Visual Studio Code. All of my extensions and settings remained in place.

Also, you'll need to disable auto updating by going to **Settings**->'**Update**'->**none**

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/